# How can I use a "side sinatra app" when deploying?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sinatra

I've got an ordinary rails app which now gets some widgets which are rendered inside a Sinatra app.

On my local machine I run `rails s` and `ruby lib/sinatra/widget.rb` which then fetches stuff from the rails app. As a result `localhost:3000` and `localhost:4567` work fine together.

How can I do all this in a staging environment? The deployment itself is working and the rails app starts up. How can I access the Sinatra stuff now?

One idea would be mounting the Sinatra app to some path in the rails app? Any ideas, suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-share-a-session-between-sinatra-and-rails) is an article from Thoughtbot, which shows two approaches on how to use Sinatra application inside your Rails app.

The simpler method is to use Rails router:

```
require 'my_sinatra_app'

MyRailsApp::Application.routes.draw do
  mount MySinatraApp.new => '/sinatra'
end
```

It's a preferable approach unless you need a custom middleware for each app.

Comment: That's what I thought as a solution so I'll go with that. Thanks!

Comment: What's missing if I get a `uninitialized constant MySinatraApp (NameError)`? This is how I named it: `class MySinatraApp < Sinatra::Base
`

Comment: This is my routes.rb: `mount MySinatraApp.new => '/sinatra'`

Comment: @Cojones have you required it in your `routes.rb`? I've updated the answer for a file in `lib/my_sinatra_app.rb`

Comment: Requiring solved it, put it into the autoload paths though. Thanks!